# pandas don't overwrite column fields when use str.extract

Tags: python, pandas, overwrite

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
11100501   bank name CTA CTE 014097729
11200502   AHORROS bank name 0550470100002042
```

I want to extract 'CTA CTE' or 'AHORROS' in a new column depend of case.

I'm trying this:

```
df['new_column'] = df['new_column'].str.extract(r'(CTA CTE)')
df['new_column'] = df['new_column'].str.extract(r'(AHORROS)')
```

but the second line of code ovewrite to 'nan' the fields that already have the desired 'CTA CTE' assigned

I can do this through iteration of rows, but I'm in search of a more pandastic and efficient solution

Comment: try using an OR statement in your str extract which is represented with a pipe `df['new_column'].str.extract(r'(CTA CTE)|'(AHORROS))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only can have one of these 2 per line:

```py
df['new_column'] = df['new_column'].str.replace(r'.*((AHORROS)|(CTA CTE))|(.*).*', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Outputs:

```py
#original:
          x           new_column                 y
0  11100501    bank name CTA CTE         014097729
1  11200502    AHORROS bank name  0550470100002042
2        23  something something              4678

#after replacement:
          x new_column                 y
0  11100501    CTA CTE         014097729
1  11200502    AHORROS  0550470100002042
2        23                         4678
```

Comment: Grzegorz Skibinski, this seems to work but I have other rows that don't have 'AHORROS' or 'CTA CTE' and i want to create the new column in this cases as empty or nan values. Any suggestion with that? Aditionaly, if you can explain to me the meaning of the r'\1'argument it will be great! Thank you

Comment: Tweaked my answer - r'\1' is regex way of saying "get me group 1" - groups are denoted by square brackets, and they generally iterate from the left to the right, and from the most outer to the most inner (you can experiment e.g. with python's ```re``` to get better grasp of regex)